# Надо вывести alert c рандомным числом спустя 15 секунд после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Что тут не так? Я в js полный ноль, так что не судите строго)))

```js
setTimeout('alert("Число" + randomInteger(1, 150))', 15000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функции `randomInteger` в javascript нет. Её либо нужно написать, либо использовать вот такой код:

```js
setTimeout('alert("Число" + Math.round(Math.random() * (150 - 1) + 1))', 1500);
```

В коде 150 - максимум, 1 - минимум.

Comment: А как cделать чтобы число было целым?

Comment: Добавил `Math.round`

Comment: А ещё, как регулировать минимальное значение? Менять 150 - 5 например?

Comment: `Math.random() * (max - min) + min;` — вот какой принцип

Comment: Не знал, что в setTimeout можно передать строку кода) И всё же, рекомендуется заворачивать её в фукнцию вида `setTimeout(function(){ /* Основной код */ }, 1500)` → https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: Да, хотел сначала именно так и написать, но подумал, что автору не стоит усложнять код :)